# axis2 client call interface data can't save, this is how to return a responsibility?An error is as follows

Tags: java, hibernate, apache-axis, axis

```
Axis2+hibernate 
client:
HxcNews hxcNews = new HxcNews();
    hxcNews.setTitle("bbb");
    hxcNews.setContent("ccc");  
    hxcNews.setAddtime(Calendar.getInstance());
    try {
        HxcNewsServicePortType hxcNewsServicePortType = new HxcNewsServiceLocator().getHxcNewsServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint();
        hxcNewsServicePortType.create(hxcNews);         
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

server-side data type for the Timestamp, the generated client data type for the Calendar, this leads to type mismatch, save the data store: no, this is how to return a responsibility?An error is as follows

```
[WARN] Unable to locate a BeanInfo cache for class java.sql.Timestamp (stopClass=null). This will negatively affect performance!
[ERROR] Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method create
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: java.sql.Timestamp
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.DefaultObjectSupplier.getObject(DefaultObjectSupplier.java:47)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.deserialize(BeanUtil.java:412)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.deserialize(BeanUtil.java:461)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.processObject(BeanUtil.java:818)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.ProcessElement(BeanUtil.java:737)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.deserialize(BeanUtil.java:646)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.processRequest(RPCUtil.java:153)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.sql.Timestamp
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.DefaultObjectSupplier.getObject(DefaultObjectSupplier.java:42)
    ... 26 more
[ERROR] org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method create
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think the issue is that Axis2 does not support mapping `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Timestamp`, or `java.sql.Time`, at least according to [AXIS2-5356](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-5356).

Perhaps within `HxcNews.setAddTime` you are converting to `java.sql.Timestamp`?

The workaround is to use `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar`.